# Image from Resources not shown after specific Comment

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

in my current project I wanted to add some comments inside, I have better orientation.

In on of my views (Index.cshtml) I have code like this.

```html
Working 

<div><img style="width:25px; height:25px; margin-top:5px" src="~/Resources/add.png" /></div>
<!----------------------------->
<!--  Starting of new Block  -->
<!----------------------------->
Not Working!?

<div><img style="width:25px; height:25px; margin-top:5px" src="~/Resources/add.png" /></div>
```

Unfortunately, the image after the comment block does not work anymore...
See this.

[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1Ffp.png)

And this is the Source code of the page

```html
Working 

<div><img style="width:25px; height:25px; margin-top:5px" src="/Resources/add.png" /></div>
<!----------------------------->
<!--  Starting of new Block  -->
<!----------------------------->
Not Working!?

<div><img style="width:25px; height:25px; margin-top:5px" src="~/Resources/add.png" /></div>
```

As you can see the tilt ~ in the working image is missing and in my second image, it is still there...

Is this a bug or a "feature"? When I change the comment to something different it works, but I'm curious why this is happening...

Comment: Your 'comments' are not valid. Its  c# razor code (not html), so they need be be surrounded with `@* your comments *@` (or it its a single line, then `// a comment`)

Comment: You need to distinguish where you placed comments - if it's HTML comment, use `<!-- ... -->` to mark comment block. If it's Razor comment, it also follows C# comment convention (`@* ... *@`, `// ...` or `/* ... */`) .